# Use a class name in CSS like a variable

Tags: html, css, class, stylesheet, classname

Is there any possibility of using the name (or part) of a CSS class CSS like a variable?

For instance:

```
.width-NUMBER {
   width: NUMBERpx;
}
```

Then in my HTML I might look like:

```
<div class = "width-100">
Hello
</div>
<div class = "width-50">
bye
</div>
```

Comment: It is not possible by pure css, You have to use css preprocessor such as sass, less and etc.

Comment: css dont have a support to variables