# using a variable in css class names, and dynamically giving it attributes

Tags: javascript, css, dynamic

I have a set of classes named class1 up to classN, and I want each class classK to get the color rgb(k%256, 0, 0).
N in this case is dynamic and has no theoretical upper limit, as the elements with these class names are generated based on user input and some js code.

I was thinking of having CSS kind of like this:

```
class[k]{
    color: rgb(k%256, 0, 0);
}
```

However, I have found no way of making CSS rules that vary based on a variable in the class name.

I briefly explored trying to use CSS variables, but those are more like constants and can't accommodate all classes 1 to N simultaneously.

Alternatively I could use javascript for the styling and have something like:

```
for(let i = 0; i < N; i++){
    document.getElementByClassName(`class${k}`).forEach(e => e.style = `color: rgb(${k}, 0, 0)`);
}
```

However, this is not very scaleable if I want to add more complex CSS (which I most likely will, the rgb value I'm using now is proof of concept), it is very inefficient and I much prefer having CSS handle as much of my styling as possible.

Looking around on the internet I did find [this post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34339042/use-a-class-name-in-css-like-a-variable) that asks pretty much the same question, and received an answer of "this is impossible". However, that post was barely viewed and from 2015, so there might be a new feature since then that could help me.

Comment: As you are saying, css variables are more constant in the root, than real variables. I don't think you can do what you want directly in css. You could try SCSS, you define your formula, it will generate automatically all your class. So still a lot lines, but not written by you!

Comment: You can use a combination of data attributes and sass.

Something like this.
https://codepen.io/Starnas/pen/yLEvBPY